# Creating a pointer in C

Tags: c

I use Ubuntu 14.10 and GCC. I am trying to create a pointer with unsigned integer type but I get this message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is my code. I used gdb and think that the error has to do with my `printf` statements:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i;
  char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
  int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

  unsigned int hacky_nonpointer;
  hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned int) char_array;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("[hacky_nonpointer] points to 0x%08x which contains the  char '%c' \n",
    hacky_nonpointer, *(char *(hacky_nonpointer)));
    hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(char);
  }

  hacky_nonpointer = (unsigned) int_array;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("[char pointer] points to %08x, which contains the integer %d\n",
    hacky_nonpointer, *((int *)hacky_nonpointer));
    hacky_nonpointer = hacky_nonpointer + sizeof(int);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try to indent your code correctly, and your English is hard to follow.
I'm not sure of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil no reason to criticize the guy's english.  If you don't know how to solve his problem keep your hands off your keyboard.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to insult. I just meant that the question was not clear.

Comment: I am not native speaker and try to express myself  and sorry for wrong expressions. I tried to change it thanks to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned int` may not be large enough to hold a pointer. You should use `uintptr_t` from `stdint.h` if available (`size_t` if not).

Comment: Firstly thanks for your interest but I considered that length of unsigned interger is 32 bit and every adress on the memory can be expressed by this 32 bit. Am I wrong?

Comment: The size of an int depends on the machine you are on. This is true for most types in C. According to the standard, it is at least 16 bits - it does not have to be 32 bit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: @EgemenSarımaden Modern computers tend to be 64-bit, yet on many 64-bit platforms `int` is still 32 bits, i.e., not large enough. `size_t` is almost always large enough to hold a pointer, but not guaranteed to be so (e.g., in a segmented architecture `size_t` could conceivably be smaller than a “far” pointer). If `uintptr_t` is available, use it – it exists for this very purpose.

Answer (score 0):

first what is that:

```
points to 0x%08x
```

you mean probably `%p`

```
*(char *(hacky_nonpointer)));
```

thats next fail

its rightfully `*((char *) hacky_nonpointer));`

here you need type in space:

```
*((int *)hacky_nonpointer));
```

rightfully:

```
*((int *) hacky_nonpointer));
```

and here no space:

```
'%c' \n"
```

rightfully:

```
'%c'\n"
```

your code must be running after that correction